# What's wrong with my SQL query since it's not working?

Tags: php, sql

At the top of my page I connect to my DB, there is nothing wrong with the connection, because I can easily show data from the table. Now I have a button at the end of the page which is supposed the edit the data in this table. However, the data isn't being updated? I have no idea why not, is there anything wrong with this piece of code? Thanks! (BTW: The echo shows up just fine!)

```
$sql="UPDATE profiles SET
    bedrijfsslogan = ".$bedrijfsslogan.",
    bedrijfsomschrijving = ".$bedrijfsomschrijving.",
    bedrijfsspecialiteiten = ".$bedrijfsspecialiteiten.",
    bedrijfsgeschiedenis = ".$bedrijfsgeschiedenis.",
    openingstijden = ".$openingstijden.",
    telefoonnummer = ".$telefoonnummer.",
    fax = ".$fax.",
    email = ".$email.",
    website = ".$website.",
    twitter = ".$twitter.",
    facebook = ".$facebook.",
    youtube = ".$youtube.",
    linkedin = ".$linkedin.",
        subrubrieken = ".$subrubriekenresult.",
    merken = ".$merkenresult.",
    brancheverenigingen = ".$brancheverenigingenresult."

      WHERE kvk = ".$kvkvariable."";


mysql_query($sql);


echo "<font color=\"red\" size=\"3\"><br />Profiel succesvol bijgewerkt!<br /></font>";
```

Comment: @JakubTruneček `mysql_query`...?

Comment: `bedrijfsslogan = '".$bedrijfsslogan."'` etc.

Comment: is there any result to mysql_query ?

Comment: is your variable $kvkvariable filled with a value that exists in the database?

Comment: Look at the related bar. That's why this question is too localized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would be willing to bet that at least some of those variables are strings - which you need to encapsulate in quotes like this:

```
$sql="UPDATE profiles SET
bedrijfsslogan = '".$bedrijfsslogan."',
bedrijfsomschrijving = ".$bedrijfsomschrijving."....
```

Assuming the first variable is a string you are trying to save.

On that note, it would probably be a great thing for your code if you did move to [PDO](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) - it is safer, more secure and you *can* do a lot more with it.

Comment: @Downvoter, is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

i think that the problem is that strings must be quoted in SQL statements...
something like...

```
fax = '".$fax."',
    email = '".$email."',
```

ecc ecc

Comment: Correct, that was the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `mysql_query($sql);`, try this:

```
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
   //there was an error
   echo mysql_error();
} else {
   //everything went ok. Show success message.
   echo "Update successful.";
}
```

That should output the error that MySQL returns.
It usually points you towards what the issue is.

Comment: The single commas were the problem, thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: No problem. Although, displaying the success message only when the query has run correctly is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
Always Use the **mysql_error()** function to track down the error 


$sql="UPDATE profiles SET
    bedrijfsslogan = ".$bedrijfsslogan.",
    bedrijfsomschrijving = ".$bedrijfsomschrijving.",
    bedrijfsspecialiteiten = ".$bedrijfsspecialiteiten.",
    bedrijfsgeschiedenis = ".$bedrijfsgeschiedenis.",
    openingstijden = ".$openingstijden.",
    telefoonnummer = ".$telefoonnummer.",
    fax = ".$fax.",
    email = ".$email.",
    website = ".$website.",
    twitter = ".$twitter.",
    facebook = ".$facebook.",
    youtube = ".$youtube.",
    linkedin = ".$linkedin.",
        subrubrieken = ".$subrubriekenresult.",
    merken = ".$merkenresult.",
    brancheverenigingen = ".$brancheverenigingenresult."

      WHERE kvk = ".$kvkvariable."";




mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

This will tell what is the error in your query :)
```